# How can I execute shell script file from laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have commands in a shell script file and I need to execute it when certain event happen in my app, I search in google to find a better way to do it so I found [Symfony library called process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#setting-environment-variables-for-processes), but I don't know how to send parameters to the shell script file cause my file will receive some arguments actually three arguments, and file located in path `/home/user/myfile.sh`.

Inside my controller look like :

```php
public function store()
{

   $process = new Process('/home/user/myfile.sh', null, [
     'a',
     'b',
     'c'
   ]);

   $process->run();

   return $process->getOutput();

}
```

when executing my function nothing happen jus get a response 200, can someone help me what is going on what is my fault or anything?

Comment: use exec('script name') to run your scripts.

Comment: Thank you @HassaanAli, it's not secure than Symfony process component

Answer (score 0):

Your codes look good. Problem at your myfile.sh. Please make sure bash script returns somethings.